# open epic fhir sandbox is throwing { "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": null }

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm trying to use the sandbox from https://fhir.epic.com/ for Backend Services.

I am following this tutorial : https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2&section=BackendOAuth2Guide :

I already register a new app,
created a JWT (using SSL keys)
tested the JWT on https://jwt.io/ : works fine!
But I cannot POST the JWT to the endpoint to obtain the access token. I should send a POST request to this URL: https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token.

The app is working for 8 months and suddenly stopped working and throwing below error.

{
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": null
}

Tried creating new app, created new certs but still no luck.

Comment: Have you reached out to open@epic.com?

Comment: We (Epic) upgraded our sandbox to a new version recently and had some hiccups.  Those should be resolved now.  If this is still failing for you, doing as Lloyd suggests and contacting open@epic.com is a good option.